# Can an account give conditional instruction to EVM

Tags: blockchain, contract-design

Let me try to specify my question with an example:

Consider that there are two accounts(`AccountA` and `AccountB`), and `AccountA` wants to send some ether to `AccountB` when a specific condition  is met(i.e. if balance of `AccountA` is greater than 100).

If i were try to implement this case with centralized way, i would do following:

- `AccountA` accepts an agreement(above condition)
- When `AccountB` requests to receive ether(based on agreement), centralized app checks condition and if condition is true the app gives ether to `AccountB`(without `AccountA`'s permission).

So my question:

Can i implement above case via `smart contracts`?

If i can, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create a smart contract between two or more parties where there are extra requirements to withdraw ether.

For example [multisig wallet](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet) allows transfer above certain amount if the transaction is confirmed by several parties.

---

Simple withdraw

```
mapping(address => uint) balances;

// I am the sender. if my balance > limit this receiver can take my 1 ether 
function Accept(address _receiver) payable {
    arr[msg.sender] = _receiver;
    balances[_receiver] += msg.value;
}

// I am the receiver and the sender gave me 1 ether. i wants to receive it.
function Take(address sender){
    if (msg.sender != arr[sender]) 
        return;
    if (balances[msg.sender] < limit)
        return;
    balances[msg.sender] -= limit;
    msg.sender.transfer(limit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to write a smart contract to implement my case and i have a trouble. Could you take a look at my sample code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77b240dcbac0a769a510ab091554e20e . I couldn't solve sending ether from sender to recevier.

Comment: You cannot withdraw from an account. You use the contract as a sort of vault holding the ethers until the conditions are met. I've added a small example in the answer.

Comment: Can the sender use all balances until the receiver calls take function?

Comment: You can add an option so the sender can withdraw the ether if it was not reclaimed in a period of time. .